# iOS Swift 3 troubles to generate PDF from UIWebview

Tags: html, ios, pdf, uiwebview

I'm currently developing an application using iOS 10 and Swift 3

The purpose of this application is to make a PDF file with the content of my UIWebview

It doesn’t work and I have to delete theses lines to generate the PDF.

`<div>
   #Test#
 </div>`

Otherwise we have a trouble with in my IBAction  :

```
for i in 1...render.numberOfPages {                
            UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();
            let bounds = UIGraphicsGetPDFContextBounds()
            render.drawPage(at: i - 1, in: bounds)
        }
```

The memory increase like if it was an infini loop

The pdf is not generated and I don't understand why.

Does somebody has an idea about this ?

And I don’t understand why ?

If someone has an idea ?

**My swift IBAction :**

```
if let contentOpt = self.contentFile {
        let fmt = UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter(markupText: contentOpt)
        let render = UIPrintPageRenderer()

        render.addPrintFormatter(self.webView.viewPrintFormatter(), startingAtPageAt: 0)

        let page = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 595.2, height: 841.8) // A4, 72 dpi
        let printable = page.insetBy(dx: 0, dy: 0)

        render.setValue(NSValue(cgRect: page), forKey: "paperRect")
        render.setValue(NSValue(cgRect: printable), forKey: "printableRect")

        let pdfData = NSMutableData()
        UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, CGRect.zero, nil)

        print("Data ", pdfData)


        for i in 1...render.numberOfPages {

            UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();
            let bounds = UIGraphicsGetPDFContextBounds()
            render.drawPage(at: i - 1, in: bounds)
        }

        UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();

        let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]

        print("PATH => \(documentsPath)")
        pdfData.write(toFile: "\(documentsPath)/file.pdf", atomically: true)

    }
```

**This is my CSS code :**

```
<style>

            .footer {
                page-break-after: always;
            }
        @media print {



            body {
                -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact !important;
                font-size: small;
            }

            .pageBreak {
                page-break-after: always;
                color:red;
            }

            .headerPDF{
                width:100%;
                height:50px;
            }


            #containerImageFuelAndMileage{
                text-align: center;
                margin-top: 1pt;
            }



        }


        .green, .yellow, .red {
            z-index: 10;
            position: absolute;
            -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
            -moz-border-radius: 50%;
            border-radius: 50%;
            width: 30px;
            height: 30px;
        }

        .green {
            background: url(data:image/png;base64,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) #14c77c no-repeat center !important;
            background-size: 20px 14px !important;
        }

        .yellow {
            background: url(data:image/png;base64,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) #ffaa01 no-repeat center !important;
            background-size: 18px 20px !important;
        }

        .red {
            background: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAkAAAArCAQAAAAA/GqmAAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAACBjSFJNAAB6JgAAgIQAAPoAAACA6AAAdTAAAOpgAAA6mAAAF3CculE8AAAAAmJLR0QAAKqNIzIAAAAJcEhZcwAACxIAAAsSAdLdfvwAAAAHdElNRQfgBw0QCiEweu5LAAAAP0lEQVQoz2P8b8AgwoAMrjD83/IfFUQxMWCAUaFhK8TC8ILhHorIF8b/g8JdLQzmKCLtNE6rLAx3GM6iiLwDACVJK/z9gk6AAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC) #c3002f no-repeat center !important;
            background-size: 4px 17px !important;
        }

        .grayBack {
            background: #eeeeee !important;
        }

        .whiteBack {
            background: #ffffff !important;
        }

        body {
            position: absolute;
            display: inline;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0 !important;
            padding: 0 !important;
        }

        #date {
            top: 0;
            right: 30px;
            position: absolute;
        }
        </style>

        <style>
            #header {
                position: relative;
                display: block;
                height: 340px;
                width: 100%;
            }

        #logoNissan {
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 10;
            top: 0;
            left: 43px;
            width: 129px;
        }

        #title > span {
            position: absolute;
            left: 206px;
            top: 53px;
            font-size: 15px;
            font-weight: bold;

            color: #343434;
        }

        #date {
        }

        #date > div {
            line-height: 12px;
        }


        #date > span:nth-of-type(1) {

        }


        #date > span:nth-of-type(2) {
            margin-left: 30px;
        }

        #date > span {
            display: inline-block;
        }


        #date > span:nth-of-type(-n+2) {
            font-size: 12px;
            font-weight: bold;

            color: #343434;
        }


        #date > span:nth-of-type(n+3) {
            font-size: 12px;
            font-weight: normal;

            color: #343434;
        }

        #gray {
            position: absolute;
            top: 120px;
            height: 190px;
            width: 100%;
            background: #eeeeee !important;
        }

        #gray > div {
            display: inline-block;
        }

        #gray > div:nth-of-type(n+1):nth-of-type(-n+6) {
            position: relative;
            display: inline-block;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }

        #gray > .green {
            margin-left: 180px;
        }

        #gray > div:nth-of-type(n+1):nth-of-type(-n+6):nth-of-type(odd) {
            margin-top: 40px;
        }

        #gray > div:nth-of-type(n+3):nth-of-type(-n+6):nth-of-type(odd) {
            margin-left: 20px;
        }

        #gray > div:nth-of-type(n+1):nth-of-type(-n+6):nth-of-type(even) {
            color: #343434;
            font-size: 12px;
            font-weight: bold;

            margin-left: 20px;
            margin-top: 35px;
        }

        #gray > #DealerLine {

            left: 206px;
            height: 150px;

            font-weight: normal;


        }

        #gray > #DealerLine > span {
            color: #343434;
            font-size: 14px;
        }

        #gray > #DealerLine > span:nth-of-type(3) {

            top: 10px;
            position: relative;
        }

        #gray > #DealerLine > span:nth-of-type(even) {
            margin-left: 20px;
            font-weight: bold;

        }

        #gray > #DealerLine > span:nth-of-type(odd) {
            font-weight: normal;

        }

        #gray > #DealerLine > div {
            line-height: 10px;
        }



            </style>


        <style>


            .marginContainer{
                margin-top: 6px;
            }
        #descriptionLineColor {
            width: 951px;

        }

        #custDetail {
            position: relative;
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            height: 305px;
            margin-top: 25px;
        }

        #custTitle {
            position: absolute;
            left: 30px;

            font-size: 16px;
            font-weight: bold;

            color: #c3002f;
        }

        #custInfos {
            position: absolute;
            top: 42px;
            left: 30px;
            line-height: 0px;
        }

        #vehicleTitle {
            position: absolute;
            top: 115px;
            left: 30px;
            line-height: 0px;
            font-size: 16px;
            font-weight: bold;

            color: #c3002f;
        }
        #vehicleInfos {
            position: absolute;
            top: 140px;
            left: 30px;
        }

        #vehicleDescription {
            position: absolute;
            right: 5%;
            top: 42px;
            width: 50vw;
            text-align: center;
        }
        #custInfos > span {
            position: relative;
            color: #343434;
            font-size: 14px;
            text-align: left;
        }

        #custInfos > div {
            line-height: 35px;
        }

        #custInfos > span:nth-of-type(odd) {
            font-weight: normal;

        }


        #custInfos > span:nth-of-type(even) {
            font-weight: bold;

        }

        #carImg {
            position: relative;
            top: 85px;
            right: 6%;
            display: block;
            margin: 0 auto;
            float: right;
            width: 47%;
            border-radius: 15px;
        }


        .containerFuel {
            width: 40%;
            display: inline-block;
            position: relative;
        }

        .imageFuel {
            width: 40%;
            margin-top: 18px;
            margin-bottom: 18px;
            border-radius: 15px;
        }

        .iconFuelOrMileage {
            width: 49px;
        }
        </style>

        <style>
            #healthCheck {
                position: relative;
                display: block;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
            }

        #topBar {
            height: 100 px;
            width: 100%;
            background: #f4f4f4 !important;
            box-shadow: 0 4px 2px -2px #e1e1e1;
            margin-bottom: 4px;
            text-align: left;
            padding-bottom: 10 px;
        }

        /*#topBar > div {
            /*position: relative;
            /*display: inline-block;
        }*/


        /*#topBar > div: nth-of-type(1) {
            margin-top: 25 px;
            margin-left: 30 px;
            margin-bottom: 15 px;
        }*/

        /*
        #topBar > .green {

        }


        #topBar > div:nth-of-type(n+2) {
            margin-bottom: 9px;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }


        #topBar > div:nth-of-type(n+4):nth-of-type(even) {
            margin-left: 22px;
        }

        #topBar > div:nth-of-type(n+3):nth-of-type(odd) {
            font-size: 12px;
            font-weight: bold;

            color: #343434;

        }


        #topBar > div:nth-of-type(1) > span:nth-of-type(1) {
            font-size: 17px;
            font-weight: bold;

            color: #c3002f;
        }*/

        .CategoryTitle, .CategoryContent {
        }

        .CategoryTitle > div, .CategoryContent > div {
            margin-left: 30px;
            position: relative;

        }

        .CategoryTitle {
            height: 45px;
            width: 100%;
        }

        /* From all div into .CategoryTitle keep the first one */
        .CategoryTitle > div:nth-of-type(1) {
            display: inline-block;
            top: 15px;
            vertical-align: middle;
            font-size: 14px;
            font-weight: bold;

            color: #343434;
        }

        .CategoryContent {
            height: 25px;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .CategoryContent > .green, .CategoryContent > .yellow, .CategoryContent > .red {
            float: right;
            margin-right: 30px;
            margin-top: 6px;
        }

        /* From all div into .CategoryContent keep the first one */
        .CategoryContent > div:nth-of-type(1) {
            display: inline-block;
            font-size: 12px;
            font-weight: normal;

            color: #343434;
        }

        #healthCheckBot {
            margin-bottom: 62px;
            text-align: center;
        }

        #fakeContent {
            height: 150px;
        }
        </style>

        <style>
            #bodyPaint {
                position: relative;
                display: block;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
            }

        #BodyTitle > span {
            position: relative;
            display: block;
            margin-left: 30px;
        }

        #BodyTitle > span:nth-of-type(1) {
            font-size: 17px;
            font-weight: bold;

            color: #c3002f;
        }

        #BodyTitle > span:nth-of-type(2) {
            margin-top: 22px;
            font-size: 17px;
            font-weight: normal;

            color: #343434;
        }

        .BodyPaintPictureContainer {
            position: relative;
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            height: 415px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            border: 1px solid black;
            background-color: #343434;
        }

        .BodyPaintPicture {
            max-height: 100%;
            max-width: 100%;
            width: auto;
            height: auto;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            margin: auto;
        }

        #bodyPaintBot {
            margin-bottom: 50px;
        }
        </style>

        <style>
            #signatures {
                position: relative;
                display: block;
                width: 100%;
                height: 450px;
            }

        #signaturesTitles {
            position: absolute;
            top: 50px;
        }

        #signatureOne, #signatureTwo {
            position: relative;
            display: inline-block;
        }

        #signatureOne {
            margin-left: 30px;
        }

        #signatureTwo {
            margin-left: 21px;
        }

        #signatureOne > div:nth-of-type(1), #signatureTwo > div:nth-of-type(1) {
            font-size: 17px;
            font-weight: bold;

            color: #c3002f;
            margin-bottom: 40px;
        }

        .signatureBlock {
            width: 340px;
            height: 300px;
            background: #ffffff !important;
            box-shadow: 0 0 2px 1px #8a8a8a inset;
        }
        </style>

        <style>


            /* new balises */

            .containerBodyDamageElement {
                margin-top: 40px;
                width: 45%;
                display: inline-block;
                text-align: center;
            }

        .containerPictureDamage {
            display: inline-block;
            width: 45%;
        }

        .pictureDamage {
            display: inline-block;
            width: 50px;
        }

        .imgDamage {
            width: 100px;
        }

        .containerContentDamage {
        }

        .containerSidePictureAndType {
            display: -webkit-box;
            top: 120px;
            position: absolute;
        }

        .iconSideDamage {
            width: 50px;
            margin-left: 140px;
        }

        .typeDamage {

        }

        .commentDamage {
            width: 150px;
            height: 150px;
        }
        #annexe {
            position: relative;
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }

        #annexeTitle {
            position: relative;
            display: block;
            padding-top: 50px;
            margin-left: 30px;
            font-size: 17px;
            font-weight: bold;

            color: #c3002f;
        }

        .annexePortrait {
        }

        .annexePicPortrait {
            vertical-align: middle;
            position: relative;
            display: inline-block;
            margin-left: 30px;
            width: 200px;
            height: 268px;
        }

        .annexeImg {
            max-height: 100%;
            max-width: 100%;
            width: auto;
            height: auto;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            margin: auto;
        }

        .picto {
            position: relative;
            display: inline-block;
            vertical-align: top;
            height: 180px;
            width: 85px;
        }

        .pictoNum {
            position: absolute;
            display: inline-block;
            margin-left: 25px;
            width: 45px;
            height: 45px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
            -moz-border-radius: 50%;
            border-radius: 50%;
            background: #c3002f !important;
        }

        .numInside {
            position: relative;
            display: block;
            top: 13px;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 15px;
            font-weight: bold;

            color: #ffffff;
        }

        .pictoDmg {
            position: absolute;
            right: 0;
            width: 70px;
            height: 70px;
        }

        .imgDmg {
            height: 80%;
            width: 80%;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            margin: auto;
        }

        .comment {
            margin-top: 30px;
        }

        .dmgComment {
            margin-top: 15px;
            font-size: 10px;
        }

        .comment > .dmgType > div:nth-of-type(1) {
            display: inline-block;
            font-size: 12px;
            font-weight: bold;

            color: #343434;
        }

        .comment > .dmgType > div:nth-of-type(2) {
            display: inline-block;
            font-size: 10px;
            font-weight: normal;

            color: #343434;
        }

        #disclaimer {
            font-size: 10px;
            color: #343434;
        }

            </style>
```

**My Html code :**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
   </head>
   <body>
      <div>
      <div id="header">
      <div>
         <div id="custDetail">
            <div id="custTitle">
               <span>#CUSTOMER_DETAILS#</span>
            </div>
            <div id="custInfos">
               <span>#NAME_LABEL# : </span>
               <span>#NAME#</span>
               <div> <br> </div>
               <span>#PHONE_LABEL# : </span>
               <span>#PHONE#</span>
            </div>
            <div id="vehicleDescription">
               <span><b>J11 Qashqai Tekna 5DR Wagon 1.6L Turbo Diesel 4WD 4 Cyl 6sp Manual</b></span>
            </div>
            <div id="vehicleTitle">
               <span>#VEHICLE_DETAILS#</span>
            </div>
            <div id="vehicleInfos">
               <span>#VIN_LABEL# : </span>
               <span><b>#VIN#</b></span>
               <div> <br> </div>
               <span>#MODEL_LABEL# : </span>
               <span><b>#MODEL#</b></span>
               <div> <br> </div>
               <span>#REG_NUM_LABEL# : </span>
               <span><b>#REG_NUM#</b></span>
               <div> <br> </div>
               <span>#KILOMETER_LABEL# : </span>
               <span><b>#KILOMETER#</b></span>
               <div> <br> </div>
               <span>#CARBURANT_LABEL# : </span>
               <span><b>#CARBURANT#</b></span>
               <div> <br> </div>
            </div>
            <div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div id="containerImageFuelAndMileage">
         <div class="containerFuel">
            <div class="">
               <div class="fuelDescription">
                  <div> #MILEAGE# :  <b>#MILEAGE_VALUE#</b></div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="containerPictoFuel">
               <div class="pictoFuel">
                  <img class="iconFuelOrMileage"  alt="imgDmg" src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/adiante-apps-app-templates-incos-in-grey/512/app_type_gas_stations_512px_GREY.png">
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="containerFuelDescription">
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="containerFuel">
            <div class="">
               <div class="fuelDescription">
                  <div> #FUEL# : <b>#FUEL_VALUE# </b></div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="containerPictoFuel">
               <div class="pictoFuel">
                  <img class="iconFuelOrMileage" name="" alt="imgDmg" src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/adiante-apps-app-templates-incos-in-grey/512/app_type_gas_stations_512px_GREY.png">
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="containerFuelDescription">
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div id="healthCheckBot">
         <p> Page 1 </p>
      </div>
      <div class="footer"></div>
      <div>
         <div id="healthCheck">
            <div id="topBar">
               <div>
                  #Test#
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```